# Forming equations for exponential growth/decay questions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

#### Problem

Dry cleaners use a cleaning fluid that is purified by evaporation and condensation after each cleaning  cycle. Every time the fluid is purified, 2.1% of it is lost. The fluid has to be topped up when half of
the original fluid remains.

a) Create a model which represents this situation.
b) After how many cycles will the fluid need to be topped up?

#### Progress

I am thinking that I will need to use something like $y=ca^x$ where $c$ is the initial amount and a equals the decay factor.  However I am not certain if this is correct since an initial amount is not given.

$100$ was the first number to come to mind for the initial amount, I just didn't know if it'd have any influence if the number was different for the initial amount just merely because of  part b) asking how many cycles.

Comment: I am thinking that I will need to use something like y=c(a)^x where c is the initial amount and a equals the decay factor.  However I am not certain if this is correct since an initial amount is not given.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the initial amount was.  you can set $y=\frac{1}{2}c$ or if it helps you, just pick numbers.  Let $c=100$ and $y=50$.

Comment: Okay, I kind of figured it'd be something like that.  100 was the first number to come to mind, I just didn't know if it'd have any influence if the number was different for the initial amount just merely because of  part b) asking how many cycles.  So the formula I have is fine? : y=c(a)^x... so then y=c(0.021)^x?

Comment: no, you aren't multiplying by 0.021 each time.  it's something different.  for example, if 10% is lost each time, you would be multiplying by 0.9

Comment: Oh, for what reason is it like that? 0.9 is like saying 90% out of 100% , is that it? So would it equal 0.979? (100-2.1=97.9)

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: so then the question becomes y=c(0.979)^x.  Now I can either use y=1/2C(0.979)^x or use complementary values if c and y  where y equals half the value of c and solve for x which would be the number of cycles?

Comment: Not quite.  See my answer.  You would set it up as $\frac{1}{2}c=c(.979)^x$  Or use values where y is half of c like you said.  And yes, you're looking for x as the number of cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After our comment conversation, we see that the equation would be $$\text{amount}=\text{initial}(0.979)^x$$

And to see how many cycles it takes to get to half the initial amount would be $$\frac{c}{2}=c(0.979)^x\\\frac{1}{2}=0.979^x$$

Comment: I understand what you are doing there, since I need to find out how many cycles it will take until the amount becomes 1/2 of the initial amount.  But to clarify, after this point: 1/2=0.979^x, should I be taking the log of both sides to find the answer?

Comment: If I were to do this, I'd have x=log(1/2)/log(0.979).  The resulting answer being x=32.67 or about 33 cycles.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Okay awesome!  Thanks for all your help! I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let the initial volume of the container be $V_0$ and the density be $\rho$.

Let the evaporation and condensation be uniform and that 2.1% of the volume is lost everytime the purifying process is over.

Thus the model is $${\rho\times(\dot V_0 - \dot V_1)} = 0.021*\rho\times\dot V_0$$

Cancelling $\rho$, and converting the volumetric rate to volume,

You get$$ V_1 = V_0 - 0.021V_0 = 0.979V_0$$

After the second cycle, $$V_2 = V_1(1-0.021) = V_0*(0.979)*(0.979) = 0.979^2V_0$$

After n cycles, $$V_n = 0.979^nV_0$$

And if $$V_n = 0.5V_0 => 0.5V_0 = 0.979^nV_0$$

$$log(0.5) = nlog(0.979) => n = \frac{log(0.5)}{log(0.979)}$$

$$n = 32.69 = 33\text{ cycles}$$